# Using different field template suggestion in different view mode

Tags: 8, theming

I have a field `field_a` that has a template suggestion of `field--node--field_a.html.twig`. Using that field template suggestion, I've modified the field to render a certain way within the template `field--node--field_a.html.twig`.

If I then create a `teaser` view mode and want to have the field render slightly different within the teaser, how do I write the field template suggestion to ***target only the teaser view mode***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like so in your themes `MYTHEME.theme` file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_field_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_field_alter(&$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $suggestions[] = 'field__' . $element['#entity_type'] . '__' . 
  $element['#field_name'] . '__' . $element['#bundle'] . '__' . 
  $element['#view_mode'];
}
```

You can remove `$element['#bundle']` but I left that in there, it will create new template suggestions so you can target view modes *by node type* instead of apply it to every teaser view mode of every node type.

You could just create two suggestions as well if you want:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_field_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_field_alter(&$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  $suggestions[] = 'field__' . $element['#entity_type'] . '__' . 
  $element['#field_name'] . '__' . $element['#bundle'] . '__' . 
  $element['#view_mode'];

  $suggestions[] = 'field__' . $element['#entity_type'] . '__' . 
  $element['#field_name'] . '__' . $element['#view_mode'];
}
```

This will create new suggestions, as:

`field--ENTITY--FIELD-NAME--ENTITY-BUNDLE--VIEW-MODE.html` and `field--ENTITY--FIELD-NAME--VIEW-MODE.html.twig`, so you would have:

`field--node--field-a--article--teaser.html.twig` and `field--node--field-a--teaser.html.twig` to use.

Then, of course, the normal code in the field template works just the same:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now you can markup fields for view modes of all node types, or also override it for each node type.

Comment: This is spot on, @Kevin! Thank you. Why do you think this is not part of standard template suggestions?

Comment: Not sure. I think there is a contrib module out there providing it.

Comment: Very useful, thanks.

Comment: @erier it may be because of performance reasons?